# How do I pass function parameters into a regex query?

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I go about passing function parameters into a regex query? 
Many thanks.

```
function match(str, arg1, arg2){
   var result = str.match(/(arg1 | arg2)/m);
   log(result) //null
}

match('claire nick steve', 'nick','steve');
```

Comment: It is traditional to upvote answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a normal string to the `Regex` constructor, like this:

```
var result = str.match(new Regex("(" + arg1 + "|" + arg2 + ")", "m");
```

If you use backslashes in the regex, you'll need to escape them (`\\`) since it's normal string literal.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

you are using a literal, try initializing the object with new RegExp("your string");

Answer (score 0):

```
function match(str, arg1, arg2){
   var re=new RegExp("(" + arg1 + "|" + arg2 +")","m");
   var result = str.match(re);
   log(result) //null
}

match('claire nick steve', 'nick','steve');
```